# HTML to Microsoft Word conversion with PHP (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am generating report in Microsoft Word from HTML content and right now I am using [html_to_doc.inc](https://github.com/rokkit/Ifmo-ais/blob/master/php_script/includes/htmltodoc/html_to_doc.inc.php)

It is working perfect but fails to display the Images as they have used image path from the server so the document will not display an image if the internet is off which is wrong. I have also tried to use base64 for this I have generated a base64 image in HTML but not able to see the image in Microsoft Word.

Anyone have any good alternative or hint for this?
Thanks for your valuable time for this

Comment: pls put some code there

Answer (score 1):

Try this -
A pure PHP library for reading and writing word processing documents

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord